# Transformer's Hysteresis Loss

Tags: transformer, homework, hysteresis

Relation between hysteresis loss and the magnetic field intensity is given but I don't know how the loss is affected by the frequency of the current. What is the relation between the frequency and loss?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hysteresis losses should be proportional to the frequency. You can visualise that if you look at the magnetic hysteresis loop. The area within the loop is the dissipated energy for one hysteresis cycle:
[image]
<sub>[Source](https://msestudent.com/what-is-magnetic-hysteresis-and-why-is-it-important/)</sub>

To get from energy lost per cycle to power losses, you need to multiply by frequency.